# How to run Node.js after downloading binary version for Windows

Tags: node.js

If I downloaded Windows Binary version (.zip, node-v8.11.4-win-x64) from nodejs.org and unpack the ZIP, what the next should I do? I'm newbie in NodeJS and can't find the answer in the docs

I see the file node.exe inside of unpacked folder and as I know it's so-called "repl".

Where should I create the working folder for the projects and the file `hello-world.js`?

And in which Windows' terminal can I run the commands?

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put node.exe on your system PATH, that way you can use it from any directory.  Here's a guide to edit path on Windows 7:

http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

You can then start it in any CMD shell or in PowerShell.

To test, start a new CMD window,  and type

```
node -v
```

This should give you the node version.

I'd suggest you create something like a Projects directory for your code in your \user dir, with a subdirectory per project.

Once you've all this in place, just navigate to your project dir in your chosen shell and :

```
node hello-world.js
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to copy the nodejs unpacked folder to the disk C and to set the PATH variable or just to set the variable and leave the folder in the current disk? In my case it's the disk D

Comment: You can put it on either, whichever suits your use case. There's no reason it  shouldn't work on D

Comment: It would be something like setx /M PATH "%PATH%;D:\pathtonodeexe"